# Finding out version, and updating to latest stable core version

Tags: updating

I have inherited a site that uses Drupal, but I've not had any experience with it before. I'm trying to move it over to a server that has *PHP 7* on, but I get all kinds of errors:

> warning: Declaration of
>   cck_facet::build_root_categories_query(&$query) should be compatible
>   with faceted_search_facet::build_root_categories_query() in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/cck_facets/cck_facets.inc
>   on line 16. warning: Declaration of
>   author_facet::build_root_categories_query(&$query) should be
>   compatible with faceted_search_facet::build_root_categories_query() in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/faceted_search/author_facet.module
>   on line 0. warning: Declaration of
>   content_type_facet::build_root_categories_query(&$query) should be
>   compatible with faceted_search_facet::build_root_categories_query() in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/faceted_search/content_type_facet.module
>   on line 0. warning: Declaration of
>   date_authored_facet::build_root_categories_query(&$query) should be
>   compatible with faceted_search_facet::build_root_categories_query() in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/faceted_search/date_authored_facet.module
>   on line 0. warning: Declaration of
>   taxonomy_facet::build_root_categories_query(&$query) should be
>   compatible with faceted_search_facet::build_root_categories_query() in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/faceted_search/taxonomy_facets.module
>   on line 0. warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/panels/panels.module
>   on line 1093. user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'IN ('hebergement')) AND (.status = '1') AND
>   (node_data_field_photographie.field_' at line 1 query: SELECT
>   DISTINCT(node.nid), changed FROM node node LEFT JOIN
>   content_field_photographie node_data_field_photographie ON node.vid =
>   node_data_field_photographie.vid INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid =
>   node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view >= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm =
>   'all') OR (na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'og_public'))) AND ( (.type IN
>   ('hebergement')) AND (.status = '1') AND
>   (node_data_field_photographie.field_photographie_fid > 0) AND ((.uid
>   NOT IN ('1','45','42') OR .uid IS NULL)) ) ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0, 12
>   in /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 154. user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IN ('promotion')) AND (.status = '1') AND
>   (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(node_data_fie' at line 1 query: SELECT
>   DISTINCT(node.nid),
>   node_data_field_date_de_dbut.field_date_de_dbut_value AS
>   node_data_field_date_de_dbut_field_date_de_dbut_value, node.title AS
>   node_title, node_data_field_date_de_dbut.field_date_de_dbut_value2 AS
>   node_data_field_date_de_dbut_field_date_de_dbut_value2, v9node.nid AS
>   v9node_nid, v9node.title AS v9node_title FROM node node LEFT JOIN
>   content_field_date_de_dbut node_data_field_date_de_dbut ON node.vid =
>   node_data_field_date_de_dbut.vid INNER JOIN nodefamily
>   nodefamily_child ON node.nid = nodefamily_child.child_nid LEFT JOIN
>   node v9node ON nodefamily_child.parent_nid = v9node.nid INNER JOIN
>   node_access na ON na.nid = node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view >= 1 AND
>   ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'all') OR (na.gid = 0 AND na.realm =
>   'og_public'))) AND ( (.type IN ('promotion')) AND (.status = '1') AND
>   (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(node_data_field_date_de_dbut.field_date_de_dbut_value2,
>   '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m-%d') > '2017-06-16') ) ORDER BY
>   node_data_field_date_de_dbut_field_date_de_dbut_value ASC LIMIT 0, 10
>   in /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 154. warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to
>   be string, array given in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 383. warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to
>   be string, array given in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 383. user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '= '1') AND (.type IN ('bon_plan')) AND (.tid AND
>   '') AND (. > 0) ) ORDER BY DE' at line 1 query: SELECT
>   DISTINCT(node.nid), changed, node.title AS node_title, users.name AS
>   users_name FROM node node LEFT JOIN content_field_photographie
>   node_data_field_photographie ON node.vid =
>   node_data_field_photographie.vid INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid =
>   node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view >= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm =
>   'all') OR (na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'og_public'))) AND ( (.status =
>   '1') AND (.type IN ('bon_plan')) AND (.tid AND '') AND (. > 0) ) ORDER
>   BY DESC LIMIT 0, 20 in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 154. user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '= '1') AND (.type IN ('hebergement')) AND
>   (node_data_field_photographie.field_ph' at line 1 query: SELECT
>   DISTINCT(node.nid), random, node.title AS node_title, location.city AS
>   location_city, location.postal_code AS location_postal_code FROM node
>   node LEFT JOIN content_field_photographie node_data_field_photographie
>   ON node.vid = node_data_field_photographie.vid LEFT JOIN userpoints
>   userpoints ON node.uid = userpoints.uid LEFT JOIN location_instance
>   location_instance_node ON node.vid = location_instance_node.vid LEFT
>   JOIN location location ON location_instance_node.lid = location.lid
>   INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view >=
>   1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'all') OR (na.gid = 0 AND na.realm =
>   'og_public'))) AND ( (.status = '1') AND (.type IN ('hebergement'))
>   AND (node_data_field_photographie.field_photographie_fid > 0) AND
>   (userpoints.points > '40') ) ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 0, 1 in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 154. user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '= '1') AND (.type IN ('hebergement')) AND
>   (votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.' at line 1 query: SELECT
>   DISTINCT(node.nid), votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.value AS
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average_value,
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.value AS
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count_value,
>   votingapi_vote_vote_percent.value AS
>   votingapi_vote_vote_percent_value, node.title AS node_title FROM node
>   node LEFT JOIN votingapi_cache votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average ON
>   node.nid = votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.content_id AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.content_type = 'node' AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.value_type = 'percent' AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.tag = 'vote' AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.function = 'average' LEFT JOIN
>   votingapi_cache votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count ON node.nid =
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.content_id AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.content_type = 'node' AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.value_type = 'percent' AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.tag = 'vote' AND
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.function = 'count' LEFT JOIN
>   votingapi_vote votingapi_vote_vote_percent ON node.nid =
>   votingapi_vote_vote_percent.content_id AND
>   votingapi_vote_vote_percent.content_type = 'node' AND
>   votingapi_vote_vote_percent.value_type = 'percent' AND
>   votingapi_vote_vote_percent.tag = 'vote' INNER JOIN node_access na ON
>   na.nid = node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view >= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND
>   na.realm = 'all') OR (na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'og_public'))) AND (
>   (.status = '1') AND (.type IN ('hebergement')) AND
>   (votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.value > 20) ) ORDER BY
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average_value DESC,
>   votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count_value DESC LIMIT 0, 10 in
>   /home/user/web/foo.org/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on
>   line 154.

I've already done a search and replace of &$ to just $, as I read that this method was depreciated in PHP 5.4 onwards.

```
perl -p -i -e 's|\&\$|\$|g' `grep  --include \*.inc -rl '&$' .`
perl -p -i -e 's|\&\$|\$|g' `grep  --include \*.module -rl '&$' .`
perl -p -i -e 's|\&\$|\$|g' `grep  --include \*.php -rl '&$' .`
```

So now I'm trying to figure out how I update all of the modules / apply all the Drupal 7 patches. I'm used to Wordpress, where it just does it all for you. To me, it seems like everything has to be done manually here. Is that correct?

Any ideas / suggestions would be much appreciated - I'm drowing a bit here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your site as follows:

- Via Drush: run `drush rf && drush ups` to check for updates. To update a module run `drush up [module-name]` or `drush up drupal` to update core.
- Via the interface: visit `/admin/modules`. Note that this is not recommended. Also core updates cannot be done through the interface. If possible use Drush.
- Manual: download the new module packages individually from Drupal.org and replace them in your modules folder. Note that this is not recommended, use Drush.

You can check your site's status via `/admin/reports/status`. A lot of information is deplayed here, including the core version.

More information about installing Drush: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: Thanks. I just installed `drush` using apt-get, but when running I get: `Drush 5.10.0 does not support Drupal 5. Use Drush 4 instead.`. How to get around that?

Comment: I think you could install Drush via Composer: `composer global require drush/drush:4.*`. Do not that Drupal 5 and 6 are currently unsupported. It is strongly recommended to upgrade to at least Drupal 7!

Comment: You're using Drupal 5 @Andrew? There's basically no chance you'll get that working with php7, the code is far too old. Php 5.2.x is the latest supported for D5. You need to upgrade to a newer version of drupal, which can't be done automatically and isn't a simple process. You'll need to come up with a migration plan based on the core/custom/contrib  modules you're using, manually rewrite any custom themes so they work with the version you're migrating to, and so on. Put aside a few days, it's a big job

Comment: Ah man, rubbish :( The worst part, is that it only gets a couple of thousand hits a month. Not sure its worth spending several days on it :( Are there any decent hosts who still use PHP 5.2 that I could stick it on?

Comment: @AndrewNewby That one's a bit of an oxymoron - any host that still offers 5.2 can't really be considered "decent", it's been EOL for years and has no support. You could run it yourself on a custom server, but it's a really bad idea IMO

Comment: @Clive haha ok, I get the point :) We are basically migrating from another server to a new one (on Linode), that has a decent spec. I may just have to see if we "convert" this site into static pages, and leave it at that (its more aimed at sending traffic to our main site, and doesn't get any real use)

Comment: @Gun5m0k3 - while your answer doesn't fix my problem, I'm going to accept it (as it would have worked if I'd been using Drupal 6 or 7, like I was thinking I had)